# Is fetching data from SQLite faster than a FILE IO in mobile devices(Smartphones)?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, sqlite, blackberry

I am creating a mobile app based on Phone Gap so that i make different builds out of it for iPhone, Blackberry and Android. It is basically a browser based app.

I have large number of files to be displayed to the user in my app (basically a e-book kind). The files will be displayed to the user in the form of hierarchy. For example

User selects a Book(Screen 1). All the chapters in the book will be displayed(screen2). Then the user selects the chapter and all topics will be displayed (Screen 3). The user selects on a topic to read it (screen 4).

I have two approaches and could not decide which will better in terms of performance and accommodating new requirements in future.

1. I will store all the data in a HTML file(each file for one topic) and display it to the user by reading the file from hierarchal folders, displaying it in the browser as it is HTML.
2. Store all the HTML data into SQLite database(each record for one topic) and fetch the data from SQLite and display to user. So every time i have to got to SQLite and fetch the data to show to user as my whole book is available in DB.

also my app is not native platform based.

The Problems i face in future will be
If i go for file approach my files will be static lying around in the folders and in future if want to merge two topics to be displayed as one file i need to do a file operation to merge it. But if i use a database i can select those two records that pertains to two topics and display it in the browser.

Please recommend which will be better

1. In terms of performance (faster as mobile devices have limited resources for a intensive DB operation)
2. Flexibility for doing data manipulation.
3. IS Accessing SQLite using Javascript (PhoneGap Framework) faster than Native language calls and will my Phone respond to intensive DB operations?For example : iOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all the details it's impossible to say for sure, but I think you'll be better positioned for scalability in the future if you go the SQLite route. With the HTML approach, if it doesn't work well, your options for improvement are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think a proper way would be to use a DB. However there are some points across platforms (for instance, the choice may depend on a total size of the data to be stored):

1. Android. On Android both SQLite and file operations are fast. All Android versions support SQLite. I have not heard about any DB size limit issues. However by default DB is stored in internal device memory. I saw some devices where the internal device memory is rather short - around 50 MBytes only. However with additional implementation efforts it is possible to place DB on SDCard.
2. BB. BB is a pain. On BB file operations turned to be much slower than on Android. I have not tried SQLite on BB, though I suspect it should be a bit faster, since it probably have some low-level optimizations, but not much faster since SQLite is based on the same file system. BB supports SQLite since BB OS 5.0. In BB OS 5.0 the DB size limit is 512 KB, then in BB OS 6.0 the limit has been increased to 5 MB, and finally in BB OS 7.0 the limit has been increased to 16 MB. Note there is also a limit on a DB query. :) In BB OS 7.0 a query can be up to 1 MB. Before the BB OS 7.0 the query length limit was 4 KB. E.g. if you are going to insert big text pieces in the DB, a query length limit of 4 KB can be a painful problem.
3. iPhone. Sorry, unfortunatelly I am not aware what happens on iPhone.